# Spool do not display information about alter while error

Tags: installshield

I have few lines in a file that's been loaded into list. In the file is line that starts with EKO-1223... I would like to get this line, so I am using a while loop and iterate over the lines from the list. I am using `nPos = StrFind(svLine, "EKO")` but the nPos is < 0 so it does not find the result, why?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a good answer, you'll need to provide more details on how you get the text from the file into `svLine`, as well as anything you know about the file's encoding, etc. (If you know nothing about encodings, a hex dump of the first few bytes of the file, as well as those including the EKO- may suffice to identify it.)

My guess is either you haven't properly loaded `svLine` at all, or that the encoding was misidentified, and thus `svLine` contains something like `"E\0K\0O\0..."` or `"䭅ⵏ"` (that is `"\x4b45\x2d4f"` in C notation). Can you confirm with a message box or in the debugger?

One alternative you could consider is calling [FileGrep](https://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield23helplib/installshield23helplib.htm#Subsystems/LangRef/helplibrary/LangrefFileGrep.htm). This could help if your code didn't load the file at all, but is unlikely to handle encodings any better. If it's improperly detected encoding and you can change the file, ensure the file has the correct BOM for its encoding. But if you don't control the file, I'm not sure what to recommend. Binary reads and manual decoding (possibly leveraging [Kernel32.MultiByteToWideChar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar)) might be your best bet.